# Modern way of accessing-reading-parsing a file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, parsing

Reading answers on this topic, I got confused. (Lots of answers, each one saying the others are outdated, etc.)

Suppose I have `words.txt` file in the same directory as my `index.html` and `script.js`. The contents of the text file are comma separated words: `"apple", "hello", ...`

What is the modern way of browser-side local-page accessing/reading/parsing that text file?

Comment: Is this about server-side (e.g. Node.js) or browser-side JavaScript, or something else?

Comment: maybe `fetch()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch

Comment: Okay, so it's about the browser. Furthermore, is this a local page or is it being served over HTTP(S)? There are limitations on how local pages can access local files (even if they're in the same directory as the file itself).

Comment: A modern es6 approach is to use fetch with arrow functions. Written as one line: `fetch('words.txt').then(res => res.text()).then(txt => console.log(txt))`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript runs in the browser on the client machine, and it cannot access the underlying file system. If I understood you correctly, you want to read and parse a file into some kind of an array.
 That's done on the server. On the server, there exists a file called words.txt, and you can make an API endpoint that will return the contents of a file.

However, you can make another .js for example *words.js* that will have an array of strings called words.
When loading scripts in html load words.js before myfile.js (myfile.js is your javascript), and you will be able to access `words` from *myfile.js*.

Example of how it's done:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="words.js"></script> <!-- Loading words here -->
    <script src="myfile.js"></script> <!-- Loading your script here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

words.js

```js
const words = ["apple", "hello",...];
```

myfile.js

```js
words.forEach((word) => {/* Do something */});
```

A project like this becomes very complicated very fast because you need to load javascript files in the right order. Because of this bundlers exist, like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) that will bundle your code and you won't have to worry about this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` in combination with d3.js is pretty good at deciphering any csv file:

```js
fetch("https://date.nager.at/PublicHoliday/Country/DE/2022/CSV")
.then(r=>r.text()).then(csv=>console.log(d3.csvParse(csv)));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Once the CSV has been parsed you can of course also list the values without the keys:

```js
fetch("https://date.nager.at/PublicHoliday/Country/DE/2022/CSV")
.then(r=>r.text()).then(csv=>console.log(d3.csvParse(csv).map(o=>Object.values(o))));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```